# Update table column on the basis of another table column

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I have 2 tables. 'report' and 'panel_calculation' are the tables.

```
report contains:

r_zone   r_address    r_status
=======+==========+============
1          8             0
2          9             0
2          6             0
7          9             0
3          2             0


panel_calculation contains:

p_cal_zone  p_cal_address  p_status
===========+==============+============
7                9             1
3                2             1
```

I need to update the r_status column in 'report' table on the basis of 'panel_calculation' table.

so that the final result would be like this:

```
Final 'report' should be like this:

r_zone   r_address    r_status
=======+==========+============
1          8             0
2          9             0
2          6             0
7          9             1
3          2             1
```

I need your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to your problem please try executing  below sql query

```
  update report r set r_status=(select p_status from panel_calculation where p_cal_zone=r.r_zone limit 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

you could still join both table even when *updating* the table.

```
UPDATE  report s
        INNER JOIN panel_calculation b
            ON s.r_zone = b.p_cal_zone
SET     s.r_status = b.p_status
```

- [SQLFiddle Demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c286/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE report r
INNER JOIN panel_calculation p ON r.r_zone = p.p_cal_zone 
SET r.r_status = p.p_status;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fa68/2)

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I have tried it, but nothing is happening.. Just can't figure it out whats going on :(

Comment: @Kalid - You're welcome. Can you please post the exact query you tried. And if possible update the [**sample demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fa68/2), explaining this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you :) I figured it out.... finally got it solved ..used this one "UPDATE report SET r_status=(SELECT p_cal_status FROM panel_calculation WHERE p_cal_zone=report.r_zone AND p_cal_address=r_address)";

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN like this:

```
UPDATE report t1
LEFT JOIN panel_calculation t2
    ON t1.r_zone=t2.p_cal_zone
    AND t1.r_address=t2.p_cal_address
SET t1.r_status=t2.p_status
```

Comment: left join isn't really neccesary in this case